# Where does visual studio deploy folders inside wwwroot in azure

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an asp core webapp deployed on Azure using Visual Studio 2022 to publish.  On my local machine I have a number of site folders and files under wwwroot like this:

```
-wwwroot
----SimFiles
----StaticPages
----Videos
----Docs
    Etc
```

The website has been working and is accessing all the data correctly but when I use the KUDU debugger console to view the Azure site structure I don't see any of these folder where I would expect to find them under site/wwwroot.

I need to directly access some of the wwwroot subfolders to clean up files but cannot find any of the data files that I know are somewhere on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App Service, you could find an option App Service Editor under Developer tools.

[image]

Click on It(App Service Editor) and then click on the **Go** link.

It will show you your site structure.

[image]

Comment: The key for me was determining that there is a wwwroot folder beneath the wwwroot folder which contains all the files from my local system.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, we could able to make this work by adding the below code in .csproj.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

[image]